# Get customer's shipping address country in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have the customers id so when I do the following to get the other shipping information the country comes out empty. Anybody know another way to get the country or know why it is empty?

```
        //get shipping address
        $shippingaddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($customer->default_shipping);
        $addressdata = $shippingaddress ->getData();
        $addressdata['city'];
        $addressdata['postcode'];
        $addressdata['region'];
        $addressdata['telephone'];
        $addressdata['country'];
```

Comment: Try using `print_r( $addressdata )` or `var_dump( $shippingaddress )` to see what data is available to you through `Mage::getModel()`. If you can't get anywhere with that information, post the output of those function calls with your question. Maybe someone with Magento-specific expertise will be of more help with that extra debugging information.

Comment: $addressdata['country_id'];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$addressdata = $shippingaddress ->getData();`

do a `var_dump($addressdata);`

whatever is displayed can be used using `->getData('varName')`

Comment: first and second line worked great but when using ->getData('varName') no info is displayed. ->getData('varName') must be used in controller or in phtml?. thank you!

Comment: varName  needs to be replaced by a proper string.To know about proper string first do  ->getData() and a print_r to see all variable names available.